# VSCode Intellisense for bound document.createElement reference

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am aliasing `document.createElement` to use as a shortcut in my codebase. Visual Studio Code doesn't appear to be able to infer the variable's type based on this simple declaration however I'm not sure how to give it the proper hint.

I have tried adding a @type hint such as `@type {document.createElement}` or `@type {Function}`. I think it would partially work if I instead wrapped it in a function of my own and declared the return type to by Element or HTMLElement.  But that wouldn't give me the same function signature as `document.createElement` normally gets.

```
/** Shortcut for document.createElement - must have document bound to it */
const _ = document.createElement.bind(document);
```

I'd expect when I type the parenthesis after my underscore that I would see the same function signature and parameter hints as if I had typed `document.createElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `typeof` combined with the `@type` jsdoc annotation:

```
/** @type {typeof document.createElement} */
const _ = document.createElement.bind(document);
```

[image: IntelliSense for bound function]

You were on the right track except that the `@type` annotation takes a type while `document.createElement` is a runtime expression. The [`typeof` type query](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript) from TypeScript takes an expression (such as `document.createElement`) and returns its type.

Alternatively, you could use the `Document` type instead. The global `document` variable is an instance of the `Document` type:

```
/** @type {Document['createElement']} */
const _ = document.createElement.bind(document);
```

Comment: Ah!  Fantastic, thanks so much!  I always get confused with where to look for this information (JSDoc docs vs. TypeScript docs).